# Select the last element of a Div using jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the value of last `<h4>` element of a div. I have tried with all the solution I found on web but nothing is working here.

```
<div id="mdiv">
    <div id="example">
         <h4> </h4>
    </div>
<div>
```

and JQuery

```
 var texter = '<h4>' + message + '</h4>' + '<br/>';
 $('#example').append(texter);
 //not working
 alert($('#example').children().last().text());

 //Not working
 //$('#example h4:last').val();
 //not working
 //$('#example h4:last-child').val();
```

as you see above I tried 3 approch including commented code but nothing is working for me. What should I do to get the newly added `<h4>`?

Comment: Assuming you've defined `message` somewhere, your code works https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/g2bp7vk9/ (the append)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`:last` selector](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) is sufficient:

```
$('#example h4:last').text()
```

Here's a working example:

```js
let texter = '<h4>' + "test" + '</h4>' + '<br/>';
$('#example').append(texter);
alert($('#example h4:last').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mdiv">
    <div id="example">
         <h4> </h4>
    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: I think this the right answer though @Jeremy M. answer works but his answer will not work in some cases..

Answer (score 2):

You should do like so :

```
alert($('#example h4').last().text());
```

There you will catch the last h4. With your code you'r trying to get the last `div#example`.

Comment: It;s working... don't know who gave you down vote but I covered that up by another up vote, thanks for your answer...

Comment: No prob mate. You can validate my answer if you wan't ! :)